# Using Skype4COM with VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, skype4com

I am trying to use Skype4COM.dll to get the list of contacts for a Skype user and to send messages to a user. I have Visual Studio 2010 and the application I am trying to develop is a C++ based one.

I have issues with importing the Skype4COM.dll into the project. Following are steps I had done:

- Downloaded the dll from http://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com
- Register the dll using regsvr32 command
- Created a Win32 Console Application in Visual Studio
- Added Skype4COM.dll to the Additional Dependencies of the project
- Tried - #import "Skype4COM.dll"

I get an error saying:
Error: cannot open source file "$(SolutionDir)/Debug/Skype4COM.tlh"

Can someone please help me with the problem.

Also it'll be great if someone can point me to a good article on how to use/configure Skype4COM with VC++

Thanks,

Raaja

Comment: I tried to import in a simple C++/ATL project that just creates a reference to one of the Skype COM interface and it worked (at least no error when compiling) (but I have not added Skype4COM.dll in the project's additional dependencies).

Comment: Question: Why do you need it to be in C++? Can't you use C# or VB.Net ?

Comment: Thanks Vagaus!
The project I'm developing is a C++ one, and the other modules are developed. Moreover I haven't worked with C# or VB earlier, hence thought will finish the project in C++.

Can you please elaborate on "project that just creates a reference to one of the Skype COM interface", where did you reference it and what was the interface you used?

Comment: I referenced it from a folder inside the project.. but as I said, I have not tried to do anything other than checking if I could compile it. (BTW: good to know you found a way to get it to compile)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Skype\Skype4COM.dll instead of the one downloaded from the internet.

Thanks!